# Python For Loop - Hierachy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do some web scraping and going to run two for loops to dive into, what I ultimately want, is the web link href.

```
website_details = soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'bodyText'})
result = []
for tag in website_details:
    result.append(tag)

result2 = []
p_tag = result.find_all("p")
for tag in p_tag:
    result2.append(tag)
```

I get the error below.

> p_tag = result.find_all("p")
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: `result` is a list you've defined. Why would you expect it to have an attribute `find_all` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `result` is a python `list` and `list` doesn't have a `find_all()` function.

You need to call `find_all()` on the soup object (possibly on `website_details`?).

Comment: How could I do that when they are already assigned? I want to dive further into them to get to the href. Sorry new to Python so need the basics

Comment: well, I think a better question is why are you looping over `website_details` and adding it to a `result` list? Unfortunately I'm not versed in soup at all, so I'm not sure what type of object `website_details` is, but ideally, it's some type of `soup` object that allows you to continue calling `find`/`find_all` on it?

Comment: What would be the code for that in terms of continually calling on it and being able to delve deeper. Initially a div then to p and then getting the href?

Comment: Again, I've never used `soup` before, but try something like this:

`soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'bodyText'}).find_all("p")`